How can I disable syntax highlighting of inline completions in VS Code?
After I updated to VS Code 1.94, the ghost text from extensions that contribute inline completions like GitHub Copilot or other AI code completion extensions changed from being grey to having syntax highlighting. How can I make it become grey again?

Use the editor.inlineSuggest.syntaxHighlightingEnabled setting (set it to false).
